# Pause notifications stream on mouseover and resume on mouseout

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I've got this stream which shows/hides notifications:

```
this.subscription = this.notificationsApi.notifications$.pipe(
  concatMap((event) => {

    return of(event).pipe(
      delay(450),
      tap(() => {
        this.notification = event;
        this.isActive = true;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      }),
      delay(isDefined(event.showFor) ? event.showFor : this.hideAfter),
      /// Pause here if you hover over the notification ///
      tap(() => {
        this.isActive = false;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      }),
      delay(450)
    );
  })
).subscribe(() => {});
```

What I would like to do is pause the stream when you hover over the notification and continue when you're no longer hovering over it:

```
<div (mouseover)="pause()" (mouseout)="continue()"></div>
```

This is where I can't seem to find a solution that works in this case. I'm assuming I have to use another 1-2 `Subject`s and then use `switchMap` depending on if you pause or continue but like I said I can't figure out how exactly.

I tried looking at [this StackBlitz for switchMap pause/resume functionality](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ivdebg?file=index.ts) but when I tried that approach it didn't show any notifications at all.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you try create `isHover` flag and add `filter(() => !isHover` between delay and tap?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak No, it feels like that would cancel the stream instead of pausing it.

Comment: But filtered observable still exist, only ticks are ignored. It's more imperative than reactive way to do this, but i have no better idea

Comment: have you tried to use combineLatest? this rxjs operator will allow you to get combine from mutiples streams, you can have 2 stream: mouseover and notification, by combining both you can put a filter and continue only if mouse over is false

Comment: combineLatest, imho, wont do: user might either never hover notifications or hover em several times in the delayed period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check** [this stackblitz interactive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5xanzq) and [this static viz example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/fa4eb1c0ed0cea4252be282ef8028a7f)

The main trick was to wait at least for

- notification show delay
- and the next message on the stream

and let mouse ins and outs to add to the delay.

The magic inside the `concatMap` does that (at least, I think it does...)

**To start**, we take the `notifications$` and concatMap a delay on it. Therefore each msg would be shown at least `DELAY` time

*NOTE: pseudocode*

```js
notifications$.concatMap(msg => 
  timer(DELAY)
    .ignoreElements()
    .startWith(msg)
)
```

**Then** we want the mouse to delay the delay

```js
notifications$
  .concatMap(msg =>
    mouse$
      .switchMap(isOver => { // < We re-delay on mouse state change
        if (isOver) {
          return empty() // < Do nothing when user hovers
        }

        return timer(DELAY); // < after DELAY -- take in next msgs
      })
      // we need only one completion event from this mouse$+ stream
      .take(1)
      // existing logic to turn delay stream into msg stream with delay
      .ignoreElements()
      .startWith(msg)
  )
```

**Finally**, if next message comes after the DELAY -- we need to still listen to mouse hovers and delay by them

```js
// store current msg index
let currentMsgIndex = -1;

notifications$

  // store current msg index
  .map((msg,i) => {
    currentMsgIndex = i;
    return msg;
  })

  .concatMap((msg, i) => {
    // we listen to events from the mouse
    return memMouse$
      // if mouse pos changed -- reeval timeout
      .switchMap(value => {

        // do nothing on mouse in
        if (value) {
          return empty();
        }

        // until next msg comes in -- we're tracking mouse in/out
        let nextMsgAwait$;
        if (i == currentMsgIndex) {
          // current msg is latest
          nextMsgAwait$ = notifications$.pipe(take(1));
        } else {
          // we already have next msgs to show
          nextMsgAwait$ = of(void 0);
        }

        // if mouse is away -- wait for
        // - timer for TIMEOUT
        // - and till new msg arrives

        // until then -- user can mouse in/out
        // to delay the next msg display

        return forkJoin(
          timer(TIMEOUT)
          , nextMsgAwait$
        );

      }),
      // we need only one completion event from this mouse$+ stream
      .take(1)
      // existing logic to turn delay stream into msg stream with delay
      .ignoreElements()
      .startWith(msg)
  })
```

For better understanding please see above mentioned examples -- I've added some comments there.

Comment: I will try this out when I get some time!

Comment: I can't say I understand what's happening but as long as it works I don't really care :) Good answer!

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I can't claim that neither :) Although, having written it, commented, explained and then rewritten again cz of a bug + using a bunch of tools to explore threads. Also, you'll have to support and extend it. So I thought: maybe it would be better to write this stuff w/o reactive code, but use good old imperative code with a bunch of setTimeouts and flags? Not sure. What do you think?

Comment: I tried that approach before but it was really difficult to even get a non-queue:ing version to work without the timeouts going nuts. I think the reactive approach is the correct one.

Comment: Oh, ok :) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, I've been writing an [article on observable pausing](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd?source=friends_link&sk=c54eb8a6d500151d016bfbb8f778f35d) and revisited this example. I've made a mistake in implementation: some messages might've slipped to view even when mouse hovered. I've fixed this now and updated stackblitz together with playground example. Sorry